# Bluetooth headphone mic and stereo audio not working simultaneously on laptop

Tags: windows-10, audio, bluetooth, microphone

I have a Sennheiser HD4.40BT bluetooth headphone.
When I connect this to my android phone, I can listen stereo quality music and while call, I can hear other person clearly and use the mic also.
Problem appear when I connected headphone with my laptop through laptop's inbuilt bluetooth.

The problem is headphone is connecting in one of 2 ways: Headphone mode and Headset mode(with mic).
 - When I select headphone mode, sound is great but I cannot use my mic.
 - When I select headset mode(or handsfree mode), I continuously hear static and very poor audio quality but can use mic with this mode.

I already read to disable headset mode to get stereo quality but "this is not my purpose".
What I want is to use headphone with stereo audio and mic simultaneously.

Comment: In a nutshell, what you want is not possible. The two modes are mutually exclusive propositions.